# Unterminated String Literal Error Message

Tags: javascript

I know its been asked hundreds of times, but in this specific case, after an hour of searching, i cant spot the reason behind the erro "untermiated string literal". Heres my code..

```
 newRow.innerHTML = '<td>1</td><td><input type="text" name="quantity' + (num) + '" size="5" /></td><td><input type="text" name="description' + (num) + '" size="50"/></td><td>$<input type="text" name="price' + (num) + '" size="5" /></td><td><input type="text" name="catalognum' + (num) + '" onChange="addRow()"/></td><a class="removelink" onclick=\'removeElement(' + rowIdName + ')\'>Remove This File<
```

Comment: Your code doesn't look complete.

Comment: jap, end, closing tag missing...

Comment: Also it looks like that `<a>` at the end is not inside a `<td>`, which seems odd if that really is a row (of a table).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add :

```
/a>';
```

at the end of your code